# How to get week period (Week Start to Weekend) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-date-functions

I have a date column 'visit_date' of the format '2018-10-04'.

I would need to derive "Week-Start to Week-End" column of format 
"Oct 1 to Oct 7" or "1st Oct to 7th Oct", which means 
I need to concatenate 2 dates - Week Begin and Week End post which I need to exclude the "Year" part of the dates.

[Saw an answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761938/how-to-get-week-start-and-end-date-string-in-postgresql) It is partially suiting my requirement, where the answer would be "2018-09-03 to 2018-09-09"

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', visit_date)::date || ' -> '|| (date_trunc('week', visit_date)+ '6 days'::interval)::date as WeekPeriod
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're formatting the data in this way? It's generally much preferred to store dates as dates, and not date strings-- MUCH easier and faster to do queries in the future.

Comment: This is for a report to be used by a business team, who would like to see the Week Start and End instead of Week Numbers or separate date columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to format the date, `to_char` is what you need (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(your_date, 'Mon FMDD')     --> Oct 1    
SELECT to_char(your_date, 'FMDDth Mon')   --> 1st Oct
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b10d60ef288fc9bdf1d9a9b808e27347)

`Mon` gives the three lettered month

`DD` gives the day

`FM` prefix removes leading zeros

`th` suppif adds the "st", "nd", "rd", "th" ending

Answer (score 0):

```
 select to_char(date_trunc('week', visit_date),'YYYY-MM-DD')||'->'||
 to_char((date_trunc('week', visit_date)+ '6 days'::interval),'YYYY-MM-DD') weekPeriod
```

The key here is the to_char, which allows custom date formats.

There is generally no need to store this type of data as it can be queried in the future the same way it was inserted above, and if you DO need to do queries on this information, it'd be better to store them as dates and not strings, however, the query above will fill the need you described.