# How can I aggregate time series data in postgres from a specific timestamp & fixed intervals (e.g. 1 hour , 1 day, 7 day ) without using date_trunc()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, time, time-series

I have a postgres table "Generation" with half-hourly timestamps spanning 2009 - present with energy data:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cVDu.png]

I need to aggregate (average) the data across different intervals from specific timepoints, for example data from 2021-01-07T00:00:00.000Z for one year at 7 day intervals, or 3 months at 1 day interval or 7 days at 1h interval etc. date_trunc() partly solves this, but rounds the weeks to the nearest monday e.g.

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', "DATETIME") AS week, 
count(*), 
AVG("GAS") AS gas,
AVG("COAL") AS coal
FROM "Generation"
WHERE "DATETIME" >= '2021-01-07T00:00:00.000Z' AND "DATETIME" <= '2022-01-06T23:59:59.999Z'
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week ASC
;
```

returns the first time series interval as 2021-01-04 with an incorrect count:

```
week                    count  gas                 coal
"2021-01-04 00:00:00"   192    18291.34375         2321.4427083333335
"2021-01-11 00:00:00"   336    14477.407738095239  2027.547619047619
"2021-01-18 00:00:00"   336    13947.044642857143  1152.047619047619
```

****EDIT: the following will return the correct weekly intervals by checking the start date relative to the nearest monday / start of week, and adjusts the results accordingly:

```
WITH vars1 AS (
    SELECT '2021-01-07T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamp  as start_time,
    '2021-01-28T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamp  as end_time
),
vars2 AS (
   SELECT 
      ((select start_time from vars1)::date - (date_trunc('week', (select start_time from vars1)::timestamp))::date) as diff
)

SELECT date_trunc('week', "DATETIME" - ((select diff from vars2) || ' day')::interval)::date + ((select diff from vars2) || ' day')::interval AS week, 
count(*), 
AVG("GAS") AS gas,
AVG("COAL") AS coal
FROM "Generation"
WHERE "DATETIME" >= (select start_time from vars1) AND "DATETIME" < (select end_time from vars1) 
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week ASC
```

returns..

```
week                    count gas                   coal
"2021-01-07 00:00:00"   336   17242.752976190477    2293.8541666666665
"2021-01-14 00:00:00"   336   13481.497023809523    1483.0565476190477
"2021-01-21 00:00:00"   336   15278.854166666666    1592.7916666666667
```

And then for any daily or hourly (swap out day with hour) intervals you can use the following:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', "DATETIME") AS day, 
count(*), 
AVG("GAS") AS gas,
AVG("COAL") AS coal
FROM "Generation"
WHERE "DATETIME" >= '2022-01-07T00:00:00.000Z' AND "DATETIME" < '2022-01-10T23:59:59.999Z'
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
;
```

Comment: "returns the first time series interval as 2021-01-04 with ..."  Can you share more information on why the count is incorrect?

Comment: A weekly count should be 336, but as the first time series is treated as 2021-01-04 to 2021-01-10 it discounts half the week as the WHERE clause only counts data from 2021-01-07

Comment: You can use: `select date_trunc('week', cast('2021-01-07 00:00:00' as timestamp));`, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762058/724039  (the output shows the start of that week)

Comment: Do you mean to get the start of the week relative to the required start date for the week, and then tweak the date_trunc function to adjust it - in this case by 3 days like this 
```
SELECT date_trunc('week', "DATETIME" - '3 day'::interval)::date + '3 day'::interval AS week, 
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to select the complete week, you should change the WHERe-clause to something like:

```
WHERE "DATETIME" >= date_trunc('week','2021-01-07T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamp) 
  AND "DATETIME" < (date_trunc('week','2022-01-06T23:59:59.999Z'::timestamp) + interval '7' day)::date
```

This will effectively get the records from `January 4,2021` until (and including ) `January 9,2022`

Note: I changed `<=` to `<` to stop the end-date being included!

EDIT:

when you want your weeks to start on January 7, you can always group by:

```
(date_part('day',(d-'2021-01-07'))::int-(date_part('day',(d-'2021-01-07'))::int % 7))/7
```

(where `d` is the column containing the datetime-value.)

see: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bc5976c70c989b20549c43f3bc680dea)

EDIT:

This will get the list from a given date, and a specified interval.
see [DBFIFFLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=48761c2a6ec7635c7b1460dd7653dc52)

```
WITH vars AS (
   SELECT 
      '2021-01-07T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamp AS qstart,
      '2022-01-06T23:59:59.999Z'::timestamp AS qend,
      7 as qint,
      INTERVAL '1 DAY' as qinterval
)
SELECT 
   (select date(qstart) FROM vars) + (SELECT qinterval from vars) * ((date_part('day',("DATETIME"-(select date(qstart) FROM vars)))::int-(date_part('day',("DATETIME"-(select date(qstart) FROM vars)))::int % (SELECT qint FROM vars)))::int) AS week,
   count(*), 
   AVG("GAS") AS gas,
   AVG("COAL") AS coal
FROM "Generation"
WHERE "DATETIME" >= (SELECT qstart FROM vars) AND "DATETIME" <= (SELECT qend FROM vars)
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week
;
```

I added the `WITH vars` to do the variable stuff on top and no need to mess with the rest of the query. (Idea borrowed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727013/724039))

I only tested with `qint=7,qinterval='1 DAY'` and `qint=14,qinterval='1 DAY'` (but others values *should* work too...)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, to clarify though I actually want the results from 2021-01-07 and not starting from January 4, 2021 So if my start date is a thursday (like in this case) the time series will run thursday - wednesday for each 7 day interval. I want to avoid rounding to a monday each time. 
SELECT date_trunc('week', "DATETIME" - '3 day'::interval)::date + '3 day'::interval AS week, 
forces the change I want but to use this I'd need to check the day of the week each time and add the '3 day' in as a variable, which I guess is fine as a woraround, unless theres a better way?

Comment: see edit in my answer to give a way solve it.

Comment: Thanks @Luuk - I can see that generates the correct time series / intervals but how do I  join this to my table, sorry my sql is very basic!!

Comment: I did do another edit.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much Luuk it works perfectly for the 1d or 7d intervals. Could the variables be adjusted to work for 1h - i.e. where each count is just 2 timepoints, i tried this but couldnt get it to work?

Comment: I do not have sample data to test that. You might want to invest some time in understanding how this can be solved (by reading my answer, and other answers), which might raise your skills in solving this too. Succes!

Comment: Okay fair point! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the function [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) you may calculate the difference in *days*, *weeks* and *hours* between your timestamp `ts` and the `start_date` as follows

**Difference in Days**

```
extract (day from ts - start_date)
```

**Difference in Weeks**

Is the difference in day divided by 7 and truncated

```
trunc(extract (day from ts - start_date)/7)
```

**Difference in Hours**

Is the difference in day times 24 + the difference in hours of the day

```
extract (day from ts - start_date)*24 + extract (hour from ts - start_date)
```

The difference can be used in `GROUP BY` directly. E.g. for week grouping the first group is difference 0, i.e. same week, the next group with difference 1, the next week, etc.

**Sample Example**

I'm using a CTE for the start date to avoid multpile copies of the paramater

```
with start_time as
(select DATE'2021-01-07' as start_ts),
prep as (
select 
  ts,
  extract (day from ts - (select start_ts from start_time)) day_diff,
  trunc(extract (day from ts - (select start_ts from start_time))/7) week_diff,
  extract (day from ts - (select start_ts from start_time)) *24 + extract (hour from ts - (select start_ts from start_time)) hour_diff,
  value
from test_table
where ts >= (select start_ts from start_time)
)
select week_diff, avg(value)
from prep
group by week_diff order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks Marmite Bomber, this is another useful approach which i'll test out. 