# Postgresql WHERE statement when date and time are in the same column

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT
scheduling_appointment.scheduling_datetime
FROM
scheduling_appointment
```

I need to include a WHERE statement to pull only dates within the last week, but the date and time are in the same column:

```
2020-12-01 09:30:00-06
2022-09-12 08:00:00-06
2021-02-22 10:30:00-06
```

How can I do this? I don't think a LIKE statement would work.

Comment: you can use `date_trunc` function and `interval` expression, see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762058/14973743) for ideas

Comment: I would assume you the column is a PostgreSQL `TIMESTAMP`, and not a text-type column such as `VARCHAR`. A timestamp is easy to compare to values in the last week using `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your scheduling_datetime column is of type `timestamp`, you can query like below,

```
SELECT * from tblname WHERE
scheduling_datetime between now() + '-1 week'::interval and now()
```

This will return you the records where the date part of your column is falling within last week.

Answer (score 3):

assuming the datatype is timestamp , you can simply compare it.
not sure wha's the problem you were facing:

```
SELECT *
FROM scheduling_appointment
WHERE scheduling_datetime >= current_date  - interval '7 days'
```